# How to get ArrayList<String[]> from a JSONObject

Tags: java, json, arraylist

Actually, I have a JSONObject like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("type", "login");
json.put("friendList", FriendList);
```

and the `FriendList`is the type of `ArrayList<String[]>`
, then I use a socket to transfer JSON to my client.

My client received the data:

```
JSONObject receive_msg = new JSONObject(data);
String type = receive_msg.getString("type");
```

My question is how to get friendList with data type`ArrayList<String[]>`?

Thanks a lot if anyone helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use JsonArray, iteratore over your list and fill the jsonArray then put it in the JsonObject

> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html